# JavaScript Server-File Manager

Tags: javascript, .net

I am developing a little software with a WYSIWYG editor. Therefore i am searching a javascript library which looks more or less like the following. Features should be:

- Upload of images and videos
- Visualization of images / videos could
  only be shown as a string
- not really needed but nice to have:    creation of folders
  Visualization of Images

[image]

My server is a kestrell-server (.net-core) but it would be nice if its only a javascript library which looks at a "free" access server folder.